# Azure IotHub, UWP, DeviceClient.OpenAsync - timeout

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect my UWP app to the Azure IotHub with the code below. I have tried a console app with the same code and it works but not on the UWP app.

I have given all the permissions to the UWP app (internet, and all other after that).
Tried a Get with HttpClient and the internet connection works

I have also tried to use the newest target for the UWP app (Win 10, version 1803)

To connect to the IotHub from my UWP app i am using a nuget package: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client v 1.17.1

On the UWP the code stops at await device.OpenAsync() and timeouts after some time

Am i missing something?

The code:

```
string deviceConnectionString = "<CONNECTION STRING>";

var device = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString);

await device.OpenAsync();

Message bla = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("blablabla"));

await device.SendEventAsync(bla);
```

**UPDATE - FIX**

The transport type needs to be defined, guess the default transport type does not work with UWP. When creating the client use this:

```
var device = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, TransportType.Amqp_WebSocket_Only);
```

Comment: The transport type neds to be defined, guess the default transport type does not work with UWP. DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, TransportType.Amqp_WebSocket_Only);

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested on my RPi3B with your setup such as

- compiled for Target version: Win 10, version 1803
- Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client v1.17.1
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.1.7

and the runtime failed (Windows IoT Core 10.0.17723.1000
) with the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

so, the workaround is:

- use the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client **version v1.6.0**

after this change my test program Blinky on RPi3B is working.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but it works with the 1.7.1. when the TransportType is set to Amqp_WebSocket_Only

Answer (score 1):

The latest version client SDK does not work on UWP using AMQP.There is a Github [issue#421](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/421) here. Please trace this issue. As Roman Kiss mentioned, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client version v1.6.0 works fine, you can try to use this version.